# replacing div tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
<div id=1 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div>
<div id="q-1">data</div>
<div id=2 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div>
<div id="q-2">data</div>
<div id=3 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div>
<div id="q-3">data</div>
<div id=4 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div>
<div id="q-4">data</div>
<div id=5 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div>
<div id="q-5">data</div>
```

I need to exchange a div of a given ID with the one after it, **with the same class**.

Comment: Do you just want o exchange the id or do you want to have the div in a different order in the DOM?

Comment: Please provide more consistent code example. Because currently there is no code at all, and your question is unclearly.

Comment: i want to exchange the div id  and it contents div has awhole

Comment: my code is too big thats y i provide a sample code.

Comment: With ID and contents swapped, only the div-positions will have changed. Is that what you want?

Comment: i dont know the all id .i know id for only one div and i want to exchange that with next one

Answer (score 3):

To insert an element after another element using jQuery, use [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/). Note that it automatically removes the element from its original context:

Here, you want something like this:

```
$('#4').insertAfter('#5');
```

Note also that IDs cannot start with a number, unless you are using an HTML5 doctype.

---

To exchange with the next element, use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next):

```
var $el = $('#4');
$el.insertAfter($el.next());
```

Comment: i dont have 5 i only knows 4 i dont know which is next or which is prev

Comment: i dont know the all id .i know id for only one div and i want to exchange that with next one

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell u im having more than one <div> in tha <div> tag\

Answer (score 2):

Generic code for swapping two elements anywhere on the page:

```
$.fn.swapWith = function (selector) {
    var placeholder = $('<div id="placeholder">').insertAfter(selector);
    $(selector).insertAfter(this);
    placeholder.after(this).remove();
};
```

Use like this:

```
$('#4').swapWith('#5');
```

You can use any valid jQuery selector/object in place of '#4' or '#5'. For your example you want:

```
var el = $('#4');
el.swapWith(el.nextAll('.' + el.attr('class') + ':first'));
```

Comment: i dont know the all id .i know id for only one div and i want to exchange that with next one

Comment: @Kiran, look at my last example ;)

Comment: @Box9 - `.after()` doesn't take a selector, `$('#4').swapWith('#5');` would literally put the text `"#5"` in there ;)

Comment: Per Nick's comment, you probably want something like `this.after(selector.jquery ? selector : $(selector));`

Comment: @Nick my bad, well spotted. Ive just reversed it to use insertAfter now.

Comment: @kiran, it should be working now. Although you might find lonesomeday's answer easier for your particular solution.

Comment: @box9, i didnt get your last comment

Comment: @kiran, I said swapWith should work now with the new code, but the other answers on this page are good too.

Comment: <div id=1 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div> <div id="qd-1">addques</div>
<div id=2 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div><div id="qd-2">addques</div>
<div id=3 class="mydiv">  <span>some data</span></div><div id="qd-3">addques</div> .....................i want to swap the id2 and ids based on id and class name. im having id of only one div and i need to swap with the next <div> having same class name

Comment: @kiran, wish you gave that information at the start. I've changed the last part of my answer to show how to do this. Also make sure your IDs always have double quotes around them: `<div id="1">`.

Comment: cant be simplifeid @Box, it seems complicated,  var el = $("#id-2");
                
             el.insertAfter(el.next('.mydata'));   "mydata is the class name for all the <div> having ids like(id-1,id-2,id-3)

Comment: @kiran, yes you can just use `'.mydata'`, but the main thing is I'm using `.nextAll('.mydata:first')`, because `.next()` will only look at the *immediate* next element. And because you have an extra element in between the two you're swapping, a simple `insertAfter` won't work. You need the `swapWith` method I provided, or something similar.

Comment: @Box( : but the middle elements clas name is different na ? so does it select the middele one if i used my code above?

Comment: @kiran, no, `.next()` will look at the middle one, see that its class name is **not** `'.mydata'` and simply ignore it. It will return nothing.

Comment: @Box9: ok thtats y my code is not working, i really didnt understand u r code, can u help me in explain wat is that class and first in tht?

Comment: @kiran basically you can simplify the `.nextAll()` part to just `.nextAll('.mydata:first')` since you already know the class. `.nextAll()` is like next, but keeps searching all the next elements, not just the immediate one. The `:first` part is a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), that tells it to just return the first element after this one with the class `.mydata`.

Comment: @kiran, that's a function that I wrote. It just attaches itself to jQuery so you can use it like any other jQuery function.

Comment: nextAll is not selecting any div im given  alert(el.nextAll('.mydata').size()); it returns 0 , is tht the reason

Comment: @kiran did you put double quotes around the ids like I said earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Since judging by comments you only know the `id="4"` portion, and ID selectors are very fast you can just use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to place it after the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling element, like this:

```
$("#4").insertAfter($("#4").next());
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/t87tp/).

In the case of a more expensive selector, just cache it, like this:

```
var elem = $("#4");
elem.insertAfter(elem.next());
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/t87tp/1/).

Comment: sory i forgot to include my <div> contain more than one <div> ta inside that

Comment: @kiran - I have no idea what you're asking now, you'll have to update your example.

Comment: var elem = $("#4");
elem.insertAfter(elem.next());
 in this i also want to add the condition like to select the next div having same class name

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you know about the div with the id 5. So what you need to do is find the next div.

```
var myDiv = $("#5");
myDiv.next("div").insertBefore(myDiv);
```

You will want to make this more robust, because there might not be a next div, and you need to handle that situation, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: i dont know the all id .i know id for only one div and i want to exchange that with next one

Comment: update your question to include that information please. i'll change my answer to address that detail.

Comment: var el = jQuery("#id-2");
                
             el.insertAfter(el.next(jQuery('.mydata'));         will it select the next div having the same class name ??