# replacing div tag using next()

Tags: jquery

```
var el = $("#id-2"); 
el.insertAfter(el.next($('.mydata'));
```

i want to swap with the current div(id-2) with the next  having class name "mydata" . is this synatx correct ?. its not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing div tag ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906926/replacing-div-tag)

Comment: Edit your previous question (as I've done for you) and it will get bumped to the top. There's no need to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The next method takes a selector (string) as an argument. By using the `$()` method (equivalent to `jQuery('selector')` you call it with a set of elements as an argument.

Just pass the selector and it should at least do something.

`el.insertAfter(el.next('.mydata');`

insertAfter() doesn't exactly swap things around, though. If the target element isn't directly next to the source element, it will just put the source element next to the target.
Consider this:
elements `ABCD`
Calling `A.insertAfter(D)` will result in `BCDA`, not `DBCA`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
el.after(el.next($('.mydata'));
```